# How to add marker for a map view in google maps sdk for ios in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, markers, gmsmapview

Trying to add a marker to Google map,but the app is getting crashed at while `addMarker()` function call,Exception details are as follows,

Terminating app due to uncaught exception '**GMSThreadException**', reason: 'All calls to the Google Maps SDK for iOS must be made from the UI thread'

FYI vwGogleMap is global and in a function I'm trying to plot marker.

```
func addMarker() -> Void
{
    var vwGogleMap : GMSMapView?
    var position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.411647,78.435637)
    var marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.title = "Hello World"
    marker.map = vwGogleMap
}
```

Any help would be appreciated,

TIA.

Comment: Normally, it means you put the code in the background thread instead of UI thread. Could you provide more code, please? So, I could see where do you put this code in your file.

Comment: in view controller at the top
        class ViewController: UIViewController
        {
             var Gmap : GMSMapView?
             override func viewDidLoad()
             {
                 super.viewDidLoad()
                self. addMarker()
              }
              func addMarker
              {
                    var position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.411647, 78.435637)
                    var marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker(position: position) as GMSMarker
                    marker.title = "Hello World"
                    marker.map = Gmap
               }
}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When performing **UI Updates in closures**(In my case - Plotting markers),Do remember to **get main thread and perform UI Operations** on main thread only.

Mistake what i did is,I'm trying to plot markers in web service completion block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
{
    var position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.411647,78.435637)
    var marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.title = "Hello World"
    marker.map = vwGogleMap
})

// For swift 3.0 support.
// 1. Get Main thread
DispatchQueue.main.async
{
    // 2. Perform UI Operations.
    var position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.411647,78.435637)
    var marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.title = "Hello World"
    marker.map = vwGoogleMap
}
```

Hope this helps for someone!

Comment: Thanks buddy! You saved my time.

Comment: Thanks for your code. It 's help me fix the problem app crash while I trying draw polyline in closure.

Comment: @naresh reddy . Can u tell me how to update marker position in google maps.

Comment: @Madhavi marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.411647,78.435637)  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

```
/// Marker - Google Place marker
let marker: GMSMarker = GMSMarker() // Allocating Marker

 marker.title = "Title" // Setting title
 marker.snippet = "Sub title" // Setting sub title
 marker.icon = UIImage(named: "") // Marker icon
 marker.appearAnimation = .pop // Appearing animation. default
 marker.position = location.coordinate // CLLocationCoordinate2D

DispatchQueue.main.async { // Setting marker on mapview in main thread.
   marker.map = mapView // Setting marker on Mapview
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 18.514043, longitude: 57.377796, zoom: 6.0)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18.514043, longitude: 57.377796))
        marker.title = "Lokaci Pvt. Ltd."
        marker.snippet = "Sec 132 Noida India"
        marker.map = mapView
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var marker = GMSMarker()
marker.location = location
marker.title = location.name
marker.snippet = "Info window text"
marker.map = mapView
```

The `location` property must be set with a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

To make a new locationcoordinate use this:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(<latitude>), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(<longitude>))
```

It's really simple..
Make sure your map is initialized by doing that

Answer (score 0):

CUSTOM MARKER

This is how I achieved it, completely programatically:

```
//custom markers for the map
class CustomMarker: GMSMarker {

    var label: UILabel!

    init(labelText: String, imageName: String) {
        super.init()

        let iconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)))
        iconView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)//Assign image to ImageView
        
        
        if(labelText != "1"){
            label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)))
            label.frame.origin.x = 25;
            
            label.text = labelText
            label.layer.cornerRadius =  label.frame.width/2
            label.layer.masksToBounds = true
            label.backgroundColor = .white
            label.applyBorder(width: 0.5, color: .black)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            iconView.addSubview(label)
        }

        
        self.iconView = iconView
    }
}
```

Function Call:

```
let marker = CustomMarker(labelText: addressCount.description, imageName: mapItem.cMapType!.lowercased())
```

Result:

[image]